# A custom PHP script does not run through URL on Magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: php, magento, url, cron

I made a custom PHP script calling a magento mage function to perform a task on an online server. The PHP file is in the root in a folder/sub-folder. I want to run the PHP script through a cron job. The script does not execute through the cron job.
Also, when it's run through the url, it returns this error message:
"The xxx.xxx.xx.xx page isn’t working"
and below that:
"xxx.xxx.xx.xx is currently unable to handle this request"
and below that:
"HTTP ERROR 500"

I cloned the whole site on another online server and after a htaccess tweak I was able to get the cron job and the script run from the URL. I am at lost after several hours of trying to resolve the issue. The primary server URL starts is in development stage and starts like "xxx.xxx.xx.xx/~name and the server that is cloned has a proper domain.

Comment: Thank you Azeezah for assisting in edit of the question.

Comment: Does the cron job log an error anywhere? Does the script log an error when run via URL? Do you get an error from the script if you run it manually? A 500 error is a script error.

Comment: i really dont know if cron job logs error anywhere on its own. The script when run through the URL (without index.php in middle) returns the error i wrote initially above. With index.php in middle it redirects to a registration page. This is same case on clone except that without index.php in middle the PHP script runs properly. The script itself runs on local server with wamp and also as I mentioned from 2 different online server also just to check.

Comment: By the way to clear further I am running cron job through the cPanel as it's a custom php script.

Comment: I meant logging an error to a backend log not what the browser gets.

Comment: i have set email when cron job runs. But it does not send any email as if the cron job did not run. I echo message in the script and found that after the require_once ("../app/Mage.php");  if i place the echo message it does not echo. also placing the echo inside the Mage.php even at the end does  return the echo but after that I am at lost as to where is the script breaking up.

Comment: @Etan
i did some more research on it and found that there is a error log file and i saw this particular output:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception' in /home/dirname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1376
I tried passing Mage::app('english'); which i found through the admin panel of magento. i tried blank, main, default but nothing works.

Comment: I don't know php or Magento but it would seem like that should be an error that people know how to solve. Try searching for that and including that error in the question here.

Comment: @EtanReisner I found the solution. The IP address domain with the ~ sign after being removed and giving a proper domain name, I changed to Mage::app('english'); and it worked. I guess both the domain and the store code was stopping the execution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The IP address domain with the ~ sign after being removed and giving a proper domain name, I changed to Mage::app('english'); and it worked. I guess both the domain and the store code was stopping the execution. Thank you